# Spark Panel Skin + target topGroup?

Tags: flash, flex-spark, flashbuilder4

Hey there-  How do I addElement() to the topGroup of a Spark Panel component skin?  For instance, if I create a custom UIComponent, then create an associative skin that uses the Spark Panel as a default, how do I add elements to the topGroup from within the skin? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didn't you inherit from Panel for your custom component?

1. Create a component that inherits from Panel
2. Declare a new SkinPart with a the same type as the element you want to add to the topGroup
3. Override the partAdded/partRemoved methods. In the partAdded, simply add the SkinPart defined to the topGroup. Something like :

   if (instance == yourSkinPartId)
     topGroup.addElement(yourSkinPartId)